# differentiate grouped rows from regular rows in ag-grid in valueGetter

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Here is my column definitions object :

```
let columnDefs = [
                {headerName: "Group", field: "group", rowGroup: true, hide: true},
                {
                    headerName: "Pnl",
                    children: [
                        {headerName: "Pnl A", field: "TOTAL_A_PNL", columnGroupShow: "open"},
                        {headerName: "Pnl B", field: "TOTAL_B_PNL", columnGroupShow: "open"},
                        {
                            headerName: "Difference",
                            valueGetter: function(params) {
                                return params.data.TOTAL_A_PNL - params.data.TOTAL_B_PNL;
                            },
                            columnGroupShow: "closed",
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

The `params.data` is undefined for group rows so it prevents my grid from rendering properly.

Would using a https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-provided-renderer-group/ solve the issue ?

How does one handle this ? How to identify the fact that those are group rows ?

Comment: where is the rest of the code?

Comment: was hoping there would be no need for the rest of the code. It's a pain to get a working version in jsfiddle especially since I'm using an old version of the enterprise module....

Comment: can you add a plunkr with minimum code to reproduce the issue ? that will help us solve this faster.

Comment: i tried your code on https://plnkr.co/edit/wW6af7JfL3N1e2dk and added one condition to check that data is available in grid before performing `valueGetter` function on it.